# Difference between getElementById methods from DOM and Document classes

Tags: gwt, dom

`GWT` offers two ways of retrieving an HTML element by its unique `ID`.

What's the diference (if there is one) between :

- **DOM.getElementById("divID") :**

> Gets the element associated with the given unique id within the entire
>   document.
>
> @param id the id whose associated element is to be retrieved
>   @return the associated element, or null if none is found

- **Document.get().getElementById("divID") :**

> Returns the Element whose id is given by elementId. If no such element exists, returns  null. Behavior is not defined if more than one
>       element has this id.
>
> @param elementId the unique id value for an element
>   @return the matching element

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Basically nothing. At some point during GWT's lifecycle the whole DOM related code was rewritten into the `dom` package. In the new package for each HTML tag a specific Element class is available, like `DivElement` to provide specific methods for these tags. For example in you example if you would use it to look up div elements you could directly use the `DivElement`. The code would for both versions look as follows:

```
DivElement divID = (DivElement) Document.get().getElementById("divID");
```

or

```
DivElement divID = (DivElement) DOM.getElementById("divID").cast();
```

To be backward compatible the old code was kept. All Widget classes use the old `Element` class which is also returned by `DOM.getElementById`. The old `Element` class was changed and extends the new `Element` class, without any extra's. So they are basically the same. In general you should just use the `Document.get()`. This all can make it somewhat confusing when working with elements.

Comment: Indeed it is very confusing. Specially because the new `Element` inherits the old one. Very good explanation. Short and simple

Answer (score 9):

Look:

in `com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document`

```
public final native Element getElementById(String elementId) /*-{
    return this.getElementById(elementId);
}-*/;
```

in `com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM`

```
public static Element getElementById(String id) {
    return Document.get().getElementById(id).cast();
}
```

So it's just a "convenience wrapper method".

But although they both return `Element` these ara `Element`s from different packages, and as both `Element`s are `JavaScriptObject` and mean the same you can cast between them ignoring inheritance hierarchy either with java cast syntax `()` or with convenience method `JavaScriptObject.<T extends JavaScriptObject> cast()`

Btw. Document is JSO overlay type so "native `this`" points at `this` ;)